# $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x} 2\sin^4 t\cos^2 tdt$ is uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

$f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined by $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x} 2\sin^4 t\cos^2 tdt$

is uniformly continuous,lipschitz ?

I can show $f$ is uniformly continuos and lipschitz for every $[0,a]$ by a standard theorem.

Comment: Look at the definitions. What do you have to show? What part of that is giving you trouble? Looking at a graph of f may also be helpful.

Comment: Can you give a bound for $\|f'\|_\infty$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $f'(x)=2\sin^4 x\cos^2 x$ so $|f'(x)|\le 2$